# fclose() seg fault

Tags: c, fopen, fclose

Why will this simple function cause seg fault?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE* file1;
    file1 = fopen(argv[argc + 1], "wt");
    fclose(file1);
}
```

Comment: Why are you accessing past the end of `argv[]`?

Comment: Because I want to run this program like './a.out file.txt'.

Comment: `argc` is the number of elements in `argv[]`, so `argv` has valid elements from `0` to `argc-1`.

Comment: @ShengchaoHuangfu: argv does contain exactly argc strings. The parameter 'file.txt' would be in `argv[1]`

Answer (score 3):

Your `fopen()` is failing to open the file, so `fp` is NULL, so `fclose()` is legitimately objecting by crashing.  Check the return from `fopen()`.

Also, by definition, `argv[argc] == 0` and `argv[argc+1]` is beyond the end of the array.  In practice, on Unix systems, it will often be the `name=value` of the first environment variable, but it is unlikely to be a valid filename and most certainly wasn't obtained legitimately.

If your program is invoked as:

```
./a.out file.txt
```

then the file name is `argv[1]`; the string pointed at by `argv[0]` is the name of the program, `a.out` give or take path information, and `argc == 2` and `argv[2] == 0`.  Don't forget to check that `argc == 2` before trying to open the file.

Always check return statuses, especially from 'known to fail' function such as `fopen()`.  And print the name that you're opening - it would have told you a lot about your problem - after checking that `argc` is set to a value you expect.

Answer (score 2):

You access two elements after the last element of `argv`. You also don't check the return value of `fopen()`, both could cause the segfault.